# How did this character travel between star systems in a ship without a hyperdrive?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*,

> Kylo Ren takes an Imperial TIE Fighter from the Death Star II ruins to Exegol. Presumably he found the TIE Fighter in the Death Star ruins, since that's where he was left.

These ships have only ever been depicted as short-range fighter craft, and it seems to be from the Original Trilogy era, given where it apparently came from. How could it get between systems with no hyperdrive?

Comment: I’d imagine he contacted the First Order to pick him up.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Maybe, but why did he stick with the same ship in that case?

Comment: he's Han Solo's kid and Anakin's grandson - you've never heard of Kylo's TIE fighter? It's the ship that made the Exegol run in less than 12 parsecs

Comment: At the beginning of the movie TIE Fighters were tracking and chasing the Millenium Falcon even in hyper-space. I suppose TIE Fighters have hyper drives now?

Comment: @tilley31 Those were First Order fighters, but the fighter on Exegol looks like an Imperial TIE, going off of memory.

Comment: Makes sense. Guess I'll look closely in my re-watch tomorrow...

Comment: Same way Luke managed to fly an X-Wing from Hoth to Dagobah in *Empire*?

Comment: @ZeissIkon The X-wing is established to have a hyperdrive, the vast majority of Imperial-era TIE fighters do not.