# How did Ben Solo get to Exegol?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Rey stole his ship, and he was talking to Han. There didn't seem to be any other ships there.

Comment: He turned up in a TIE-Fighter. I think we can reasonably assume he found one in the wreckage of the Death Star.

Comment: Four people have now asked similar question. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224947/how-did-this-character-leave-endors-moon-in-the-rise-of-skywalker?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224777/how-did-this-character-travel-between-star-systems-in-a-ship-without-a-hyperdriv?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224864/how-did-kylo-ren-travel-to-the-other-planet-in-the-tie-fighter